# C# array, String must be exactly one character long

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, split

I'm pretty fluent but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I'm attempting to take data from a web output and parse it into an array by "br /"'s and spaces. Thanks for any help in advance. I'm getting the error "String must be exactly one character long" on the line `string[] outputarray = ieoutput.Split(char.Parse("<br />"));` towards the bottom. Thanks again.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class UserData : MonoBehaviour
{
    // URL of your webserver
    string weburl = "127.0.0.1";
    string uid = "?uid=" + "219844";
    string secret = "secret=" + "428032";
    string php;
    string output;
    string[] outputarray;
    void Start()
    {
        Read();
    }
    void Generate(){
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("uid"))
        {
            uid = PlayerPrefs.GetString(uid);
            secret = PlayerPrefs.GetString(secret);
        }
        else {
            StartCoroutine(newUser("newuser", weburl, "genuser.php"));
        }       
    }
    void Read()
    {
        php = "read.php";
        StartCoroutine(readUser("read", weburl, "read.php", uid, secret));
    }
    IEnumerator newUser(string usage, string serverurl, string phpfile) {
        string ieusage = usage;
        string url = serverurl;
        string iephp = phpfile;
        if (ieusage == "newuser"){
            UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url + "/userdata/" + iephp);
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();
            output = www.downloadHandler.text;
            Debug.Log(output);
 
            if (www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success) {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
            }
        }
    }
    IEnumerator readUser(string usage, string serverurl, string phpfile, string userid, string usersecret) {
        string ieusage = usage;
        string url = serverurl;
        string iephp = phpfile;
        string ieuid = userid;
        string iesecret = usersecret;
        string ieoutput = "";
        if (ieusage == "read"){
            UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url + "/userdata/" + iephp + ieuid + "&" + iesecret);
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();
            output = www.downloadHandler.text;
            ieoutput = output;
            Debug.Log(output);
 
            if (www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success) {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
            }
        }
        string[] outputarray = ieoutput.Split(char.Parse("<br />"));
        for(int i = 0; i < outputarray.Length; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log(outputarray[i]);
        }
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: `char.Parse("<br />")` <-- This does not do what you think it does.

Comment: I'd be lying if I said I didn't grab it from an example of splitting to an array.

Comment: Well, whatever code it was, I can assure you that code is completely incorrect - and I disagree with your self-assessment that you are "pretty fluent" considering that the documentation for `Char.Parse` makes it very clear that the argument value must have exactly 1 character in it - and the exception message is self-explanatory. This suggests that you do not yet understand what a _character-value_ is, which is a very fundamental unit in programming, therefore you cannot be "pretty fluent".

Comment: Are you just trying to split by `"<br />"`?

Comment: What do you suggest I use instead if you don't mind.

Comment: yes @Llama also another delimiter if possible, new line etc. I'm parsing PHP output

Comment: Are you in control of the PHP side?

Comment: Yeah, I wrote the backend an hour or two ago, I'm just working on interfacing with it in c#.

Comment: In that case, I would strongly suggest using something like JSON to exchange data between PHP and C#.

Comment: @Llama actually I would rather simply use `\n` and separate using that. `JSON` would add unnecessary character overhead .. if it is just about splitting new lines ... then why not use the new line char? ;)

Comment: There is no string.Split(string) in .NET Framework only .NET Core. They are using Unity3D which uses Mono, which is .NET Framework. 

Manually parsing strings is not prefered in the long run. They should create a simple Class that represents the data they want to transfer (data transfer object), and serialize and deserialize using JSON. Then you work with objects instead of strings.

Comment: @DSander as said if OP actually wants to get something line-wise I would say using JSON is quite an unnecessary overhead for this ... simply split on `\n` as I mentioned in my answer. Either way since OP doesn't show the actual use case / PHP code we can only make assumptions on this regard and have to more or less stick to the title and asked question ;)

Comment: @DSander Unity does **not** use `.Net Framework`. They use a ".Net 4.6 equivalent" which actually supports both [`.Net Standard 2.1` and `.Net Framework`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/dotnetProfileSupport.html) so `string.Split(string)` is absolutely valid in Unity ... maybe you should actually try and confirm what you say before stating that most of this answer is wrong - Edit: Ok fair enough Standard 2.1 is only since Unity 2021, before it was only Standard 2.0 ;)

Comment: I didn't say Unity uses .NET Framework. I specifically said Unity uses Mono. Mono is open source .NET Framework project. However, that is not fully true because Unity has their own custom fork of Mono. Yes, they did recently release 2021 version, and you are right they have .NET Standard 2.1 now (this I didn't realize). - Funny enough I did test everything in my own unity project, but used "Recommended Release" of Unity.

Answer (score 1):

```
char.Parse("<br />")
```

will give you a `FormatException` as [`char.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.char.parse) expects a `string` with a length of exactly `1` as the error message tells you.

---

**In Unity 2020 and before**

You want to use [`string.Split(string[], System.StringSplitOptions)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netstandard-2.1#System_String_Split_System_String___System_StringSplitOptions_)

```
var outPutArray = ieoutput.Split(new string []{"<br />"}, System.StringSplitOptions.None);
```

**Since Unity 2021 which now supports `.Net Standard 2.1`**

You want to simply use [`string.Split(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netstandard-2.1#System_String_Split_System_String_System_StringSplitOptions_)

```
var outPutArray = ieoutput.Split("<br />");
```

---

Or - since most commonly the [`<br>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) tag is actually used without the closing `/` - maybe actually with multiple separator options e.g.

```
var outPutArray = ieoutput.Split(new string []{"<br />", "<br>", "<br/>"}, System.StringSplitOptions.None);
```

---

Since in general there are multiple ways how to exactly write these HTML tags in order to match all the different ways to write this you could also rather use [`Regex.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split) like e.g.

```
var outPutArray = Regex.Split(ieoutput, "<[Bb][Rr].*?>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Here you match anything that

- Begins with `<br` (or `<BR`, `<Br` etc)
- Ends with the next `>`

not matter what comes between these, even if it is line breaks (see [`RegexOptions.Singleline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions#fields)

See [Regex Example and further Explanation on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/DP72cs/1)

---

However as was already suggested, if you can change the output format actually the simplest solution of all would be rather use line breaks (`\n`). It is a single character so you can simply use

```
var outPutArray = ieoutput.Split('\n');
```

if your content is very big and you do not necessarily need the entire content of the `outPutArray` at the same time you could even consider using a [`StringReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.stringreader) and [`StringReader.ReadLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.stringreader.readline#System_IO_StringReader_ReadLine) in order to handle the lines one by one without allocating the entire array and parsing the entire string all advance.

Comment: @Ruzihm thanks for the edit ;) I included the example for a single string again

Answer (score -2):

If you absolutely must do it the way you are doing it. If you are using Unity version 2020 and below.:

```
string[] outputarray = ieoutput.Split(new string[] {"<br/ >"}, System.StringSplitOptions.None);
```

If you are using Unity version 2021 and above:

```
string[] outputarray = ieoutput.Split("<br/ >");
```

Otherwise, since it seems you control the PHP output too, I recommend having the PHP output a JSON string. Then use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to convert JSON string to an Object.

For example your PHP can do this:

```
<?php
  $arr = array('Username' => 'DSander', 'UUID' => 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
  echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

It will output this:

```
{
  "Username" : "DSander",
  "UUID" : "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
}
```

Then you can have a simple Data Transfer Object for serializing and deserializing like this in Unity:

```
[Serializable]
public class UserDTO
{ 
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string UUID { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use Newtonsoft.Json or other JSON libraries to deserialize the object like this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

UserDTO user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserDTO>(ieoutput);
Debug.Log(user.Username);
```

NOTE: In Unity package manager you must click + icon, click "add by git url", then type "com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json" to get Newtonsoft dependency in your project.

You can also serialize the User and send it to your PHP endpoint like this:

```
UserDTO user = new UserDTO
{
    Username = "DSander",
    UUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
};

// serialize object to string
string userJsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user, Formatting.Indented);

// create POST form data
Dictionary<string, string> postData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
postData.Add("userJsonData", userJsonData);

// make POST request with data
UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(url + "/userdata/" + iephp, postData);
```

Then on PHP side you can use json_decode:

```
<?php
  $obj = json_decode($_POST["userJsonData"]);
  print $obj->{'Username'}; // DSander
?>
```

Comment: `String.Split(char[])` will split on _any_ of the provided `char`s, not necessarily together and not necessarily in that order.  You want `String.Split(string)`.

Comment: Lance, you are incorrect. String.Split(string) only exists in .NET Core. They tagged their question as Unity3D which uses Mono. That means it is .NET Framework and the solution is to use String.Split(string[], StringSplitOptions). I made a silly mistake in my response last night using char[] when it should be string[]. I have edited my solution.

Comment: This answer has some good stuff in it. Definitely worth an upvote for addressing the xy problem of how asker can send data effectively.

Comment: @Ruzihm I think that the XY problem is based on assumptions so far. Since we don't know OP's actual use case and neither the PHP code I would guess we have to assume for now OP actually wants individual lines ... for this a JSON is only overhead and simply splitting by `\n` would be more efficient as mentioned ... but as said that is based on assumptions until we get further input. So for now I would rather stick to the request / issue which is primarily how to split the string correctly ;)

Comment: @DSander Unity does **not** use `.Net Framework`. They use a ".Net 4.6 equivalent" which actually supports both [`.Net Standard 2.1` and `.Net Framework`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/dotnetProfileSupport.html) so `string.Split(string)` is absolutely valid in Unity ... maybe you should actually try and confirm what you say before stating that most of this answer is wrong - Edit: Ok fair enough Standard 2.1 is only since Unity 2021, before it was only Standard 2.0 ;)

Comment: I didn't say Unity uses .NET Framework. I specifically said Unity uses Mono. Mono is open source .NET Framework project. However, that is not fully true because Unity has their own custom fork of Mono. Yes, they did recently release 2021 Unity version, and you are right they have .NET Standard 2.1 now (this I didn't realize). But you are wrong again, it only supports Split(String, StringSplitOptions). - Funny enough I did test everything in my own unity project but I used "Recommended Release" of Unity.

Comment: @derHugo Nothing I said was based on assumptions. The member that asked the question said in comments they have full control of the PHP. It is very clear what the member is trying to accomplish, and their current implementation is not ideal and difficult to maintain in the long run. Serialization of a DTO for communicating with a web server is the proper design pattern for this use case. Not parsing strings.